# In the subsequent communication between user and appserver, how does app server know who the user is and what his token was?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, access-token

In Oauth and Openidconnect, the appserver endpoint invocation starts the Oauth flow and the app server gets the token from the auth server and is able to pass the token to resource server to access resources (delegation) on behalf of the resource owner.

The token exchange happens between the app server and resource server, and the token never arrives at the end users browser.

Q1: Does the app server store the token against the user?

Q2: At a subsequent appserver endpoint invocation by the user, how does the appserver know who the user is and which token is to be used to access the resource server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes. The app server will store the token for each user.

(2) It uses cookie to maintain the user session. The idea is that after confirming the user is authenticated (i.e get the access token) successfully , the app server will generate an unique session ID for this user and associate this session Id to the user 's access token. This session ID will then be sent back to the user 's browser as a cookie such that when the user 's browser sends subsequent requests to the app server , the app server can get back this session ID from the cookie and use it to get back his access token.

Comment: Will the app server in the background at regular intervals request the auth server for new token so that token isn't expired?

Comment: no need. You just perform checking if the access token is expired or not whenever the app server send the HTTP request to the resource server.  See my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70997548/339637) . And consider to upvote them if you find my answer is helpful to you . thanks.

Comment: Assuming cookie is not a possibility, for example if the end user uses a mobile app, then I believe instead of cookie the end user can be sent a jwt containing the token? If yes, and assuming jwt expiry is set to 1 day, then the user may be kicked out while using the app. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I am not familiar with mobile app . but from what i see at [here](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-for-mobile-apps-best-practices/#using-a-system-browser-component) , it is suggested to perform the OAuth flow inside a system browser component such that you can use cookie

Comment: Suppose cookie is stolen then what is general practice to invalidate the cookie?

Comment: it depends on the the app server capability.For example in the Java world , tomcat allow to configure the expiry time of the session , and also provide an API / admin console to invalidate a particular session.

Comment: And how is the cookie expiry managed? Assume the cookie expiry is set to 30 minutes initially and while the user is using the application, at the 30th minute he gets kicked out of the app? Is there any way for the application to send new cookie rather than kicking out the user?

Comment: in this case and from what i experience in the Tomcat case, it will already help to ensure the session has always update with the expiry time to 30 mins whenever there are HTTP response sent back to the user browser for the same session . that mean the user will only kick out the app once he is idle for 30 mins.